# Indian citizen, married to Australian permanent resident, travelling from Australia to New Zealand - visa required?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia, new-zealand

I am an Indian citizen married to a permanent resident of Australia. I have a tourist visa for Australia. Would I require a separate visa to travel to New Zealand? If yes, what visa should I apply for for a holiday?

Answer (score 10):

According to the New Zealand immigration site, yes you will need a separate visa:

> You do not need a visa to visit New Zealand if you are:
>
> - A New Zealand or Australian citizen or resident,
> - A UK citizen and/or passport holder (you can stay up to six months), or
> - A citizen of a country which has a visa waiver agreement with New Zealand (you can stay up to three months).
>
> If you don’t meet the above, then you’ll need a visitor visa, which allows you to holiday in New Zealand for up to nine months.

http://www.newzealand.com/uk/visas-and-immigration/

India is not on the list of visa waiver agreement countries, so yes you will need a visa in advance.

The Australian visa or your spouses permanent residency doesn't look to circumvent these requirements in your case.